# How to find density of states (DOS) for a nanoribbon (NR)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, computational-physics, greens-functions, density-functional-theory

I have a nanoribbon (NR) which is constructed of $N$ 1D chains. The Hamiltonian is written as the following:(for only N=3)

$$
H=
\begin{bmatrix}
H_0&H_{12}&0\\
H_{21}&H_0&H_{23}\\
0&H_{32}&H_0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
here $H_0$ is the bulk Hamiltonian and $H_{ij}$ is representing hopping between $i$ and $j$ chains. I have calculated the sub-band structure of this lattice model which shows that there are edge states on both the upper and lower edge. The bulk has bandgap around $1.5$ energy units. The sub-band structure diagram shows that there are edge modes around $1.5$ energy units.

Now, I want to calculate the density of states (DOS) as a function of the position of the 1D chain of NR. For example, I want to construct plots that represent that when the energy is $1.5$ energy units the DOS of states is non-zero only at edges of NR.

Can someone please give me a starting point that how can I construct this kind of plot. I think Green's functions can do this but I could not find any proper article which is discussing DOS as a function of chain position.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: 1 month with no answer, you might try https://materials.stackexchange.com